# Submit form after selecting items from multiple dropdown lists - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Here is my HTML

```
<form action="processForm.html" method="post">
    <label for="InputOne">Input One</label>
    <select id="InputOne">
        <option val="1">Item</option>
        <option val="2">Item</option>
        <option val="3">Item</option>
        <option val="4">Item</option>
    </select>

    <label for="InputTwo">Input Two</label>
    <select id="InputTwo">
        <option val="1">Item</option>
        <option val="2">Item</option>
        <option val="3">Item</option>
        <option val="4">Item</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

How do I enable the user to select from multiple dropdown lists and then hit a Submit button? I found this answer [How to submit form on change of dropdown list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231157/how-to-submit-form-on-change-of-dropdown-list). It's close, but I don't think it's what I want. This will submit after a single dropdown list.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I want to have multiple select elements.

Comment: From question: *"to select from multiple dropdown lists"*

Comment: Do you mean that you want to trigger the submission of the form after multiple `<select>` elements have been changed? What is your criteria? Your question is unclear, because the submission of the form is allowed by default, unless you mean disabling the submission of the form until a certain criteria (that you have you evaluate on= is met.

Comment: I want the submission to trigger upon clicking a Submit button.

Comment: You must define a <form> tag in order to active submit input.

Comment: @Gudmundur First, wrap everything you want to submit in a `<form>` element. Declare the appropriate form action and method as needed. The `<input type="submit" value="Submit">` will submit the form automatically — that's part of the charm of HTML.

Comment: @jedema that was omitted for your convenience. Imagine a form around my code

Comment: @Terry But does it submit the list if it isn't inside an input tag?

Comment: @Gudmundur So, what is your question again? If it is wrapped in the form element, the form should submit just fine. You need to elabourate on what kind of behavior you expect, or at least what went wrong.

Comment: @Gudmundur `<select>` is also an input element. Its selected option's value will be submitted.

Comment: Oooh, I see. In that case, I have no problem at all. Sorry for wasting everybody's time on this

Comment: @Gudmundur Do you need to collect the selected values on the client or on the server side? This is pure server side.

Comment: I need to collect them on the client side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer

```
<form id="my-form" method="post">

    <select name="first-list" multiple="multiple" size="10">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="1">first</option>
        <option value="2">second</option>
        <option value="3">third</option>
    </select>

    <select name="second-list" multiple="multiple" size="10">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="1">first</option>
        <option value="2">second</option>
        <option value="3">third</option>
    </select>

    <!-- use this for client-side processing -->
    <input type="button" name="button" value="submit" />

    <!-- use this for server-side processing -->
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />

</form>
```

EDIT

```
//  
// Collecting selected items from one or more multiple select-lists 
//
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("button").onclick = function(){
    var lists = document.getElementsByTagName('SELECT'), chosen = [], temp = [], list = {}, i, j; 
    for(i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
        list = lists[i];
        temp = [];
        for(j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
          if(list[j].selected) temp.push(list[j].value);  
        }
        chosen.push(temp);
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(chosen));
    // you will have JSON like this [["1","4","5"],["6","7"]]
};
```

Now, you have a JSON object ready to send on your server. If you have any doubts how to do it, check my previous answer on topic [how to send and receive JSON data with JavaScript using POST and GET method.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468459/sending-a-json-to-server-and-retrieving-a-json-in-return-without-jquery/24468752#24468752)

And check the working [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/hineloha/1/edit).

Comment: OP mentioned that he wanted multiple `<select>` elements, not multiple options within one.

Comment: Read the question again :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly. You're having trouble submitting the data from both select dropdown.

I was facing the same problem, but adding `enctype='multipart/form-data'` to the form class solved it