# double click on the item's doesnt work in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, events

In my project, I have three dropdown lists but when I Double click on them to open Event nothing happens.
also when I go to properties-Event Nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

There can only be one `<form>` in one page, and only one "submit " button in one `<form>`. Check whether you put more than one "submit" button in your form.

If you want to submit multiple dropdown lists, you could link to

[Submit form after selecting items from multiple dropdown lists - JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531815/submit-form-after-selecting-items-from-multiple-dropdown-lists-javascript)

if you want to submit in your dropdown list, you could link to

[How to submit form on change of dropdown list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231157/how-to-submit-form-on-change-of-dropdown-list)