# how to send json data via get just as jquery does

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to develop a function to send json data via `get` method using javascript instead of `curl`.

And it also works fine with the `get` method of jquery ajax api.For example,

```
$.ajax({
    url     : url,
    type    : "GET",
    data    : json,
    dataType: "json",
    //.....
    //other code here.
})
```

But something wrong happened, when I try to send the **same** json data by the follow code as someone else suggest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468459/sending-a-json-to-server-and-retrieving-a-json-in-return-without-jquery).

```
xmlhttp.open("GET",url+"?pretty="+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(json)),true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
xmlhttp.send();
```

However,it seems that the json data is too large to be encoded inside the url, and the url was truncated.

**So, I wander how I can send the large json with javascript just as the jquery does.**

Comment: IS the server returning  414 (Request-URI Too Long) status i.e  an URI is longer than the server can handle.?

Comment: No,the server return 200.I has used Wireshark to capture the packet, and the head of request packet shows just like "[truncated] OPTIONS (something else)", so I think that the request url has been truncated before being sent.

Comment: There is a limit to send packet through url beyond which you need to use post. I guess it would be getting truncated after 255 characterss

Comment: Yep.But it's a little confused that I send the same size data by jquery's ajax api.And I wanna know how to send the json without jquery.