# How to map json response to UI in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

```
SERVICES.startconference(meet.value, participants, function(res) {

Log.d("div", "getting success response and posting to new tab", res&& res.OUTERHTML);

.....

}
```

Comment: add some more details to your question.

Comment: There is a response coming from api which is having meeting name, access code , conference id, date and time and participants. I need to display these details dynamically at run time when the meeting starts. How can I make UI accordingly?

Comment: Edit your question and add it there

Comment: I can see you are new to stackoverflow. make sure to learn how to use this site. have a glance at https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: If my answer meets your question, please mark it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code you can use :

```
    <script>
    let use_api = function(){
        req = new XMLHttpRequest()
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        req.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status==200){
               let data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
               //here you should update your UI with the received data!  
            }
        }
        let req_body = JSON.stringfy({"username":"asdfasdf"}) //username is just an example, you should write things you want to send to API endpoint
        req.open('POST',url,true)
        req.send(req_body)

    }
</script>
```

Have a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468459/sending-a-json-to-server-and-retrieving-a-json-in-return-without-jquery) too.

 Good Luck.