# How to use XMLHttpRequest while telling site to do something?

Tags: javascript, ajax

First of all I have to say that I have ***NO EXPERIENCE*** in Ajax and I just need this one explanation in order for me to create a simple chrome extension.
There is not much I could find on internet even tho I believe this is very simple.
I need a part of code where I would "call" url from website and I need to adjust certain arguments in that url.

**Request URL**:http://URL_OF_THE_WEBSITE/v1/send?token=TOKEN_VALUE

**Request Method**:POST

**Request Payload** :

{amount: 1, user_id: 12345678}

amount: 1
user_id: 12345678

(this is something I get from Network *panel- with url and token changed to real things* - while calling url automatically from website, but I need to be able to call it manually too.)

So I have an idea of mixing AJAX(which I don't know) and JS in order for me to call this url.
I would use variables for both TOKEN_VALUE and amount&user_id, but I don't know how to even call that url and how to set "request payload" in order for site to do the thing I want it to do.

I would really appreciate if someone would be kind enough to help :)

Work I have done, but doesn't work:

```
var request=new XMLHttpRequest;
request.open("POST","https://URL_OF_THE_WEBSITE/v1/send?token=TOKEN_VALUE"),request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"),request.Payload("user_id=12345678&amount=5");
```

I basically tried to remake an example I found online, but it didn't work out, therefore I need someone to actually explain to me how this works and how can I adjust arguments that I need.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468459/sending-a-json-to-server-and-retrieving-a-json-in-return-without-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function callAjax() {
    // the XMLHttpRequest returns the ajax object that has several cool methods, so you store it in the request variable
    // @data contains the $_POST[amount],$_POST[user_id],$_POST[whatever] since we are using POST method, if you're using PHP as a server side language
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        url = 'place_here_the_url_only',
        data = 'amount=1&user_id=12345678&whatever=dataYouWantToSendToServerFromBrowser',
        token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;

    // when the server is done and it came back with the data you can handle it here
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            // do whatever you want!
            console.log("The request and response was successful!");
       }
    };

    // method post, your giving it the URL, true means asynchronous
    request.open('POST', url, true);
    // set the headers so that the server knows who is he talking to, I'm using laravel 5.5
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    // Token needed
    request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
    // then you send the data and wait for the server to return the response
    request.send(data);
}
```

## Ajax: Asynchronous JavaScript And XML

It is a mean of communication between the browser and the server hosting the website, it cannot call any other server.

**Asynchronous** means the website continues to function normally, until the request is returned from the server and the:

```
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) { }
```

gets triggered