# Sending and reading data to AWS Lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

So i have setup a lambda function to upload a txt file to S3. How do i send data to the function using API Gateway?

Ive setup API Gateway to have a POST method.

here is my Lambda function

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    data = 'Totally awesome sword design' #event['data']

    filename = 'awesomeSword2' #event['filename']

    object = s3.Object(BUCKET_NAME, KEY + filename + '.txt')
    object.put(Body=data)
```

I just need to know how to send data and filename to the function (and read it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lambda will be invoked with the data that you send with the POST request.

For example, let's say that you make a POST request to your API gateway with this JSON:

> {"data": "some data"}

The lambda function will receive in the event argument a proper Python dictionary:

> {'data': 'some data'}

Then you can do something like that:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    data = event.get('data') 
    # this will avoid raising an error if event doesn't contain the data key

    # do whatever you like with Data
```

Comment: so how do i make the post request? The app is using javascript.

Comment: Are you using specific libraries in the App? Here you can find a way to send a POST without using any libs .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468459/sending-a-json-to-server-and-retrieving-a-json-in-return-without-jquery

Comment: i think this should work. where do i find the url to post to?

Comment: This is something that you can retrieve from the API Gateway in AWS

Comment: i got the url, and used your link however im getting this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()

using Gateway's console ive manged to get it work

Comment: How the URL looks like? It should be something like https://4z9giyi2c1.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/deployment_stage/your_endopoint

Comment: like this: https://---------.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/test/magiswordsupload

Comment: Can you try to send something using Python requests?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173223/discussion-between-nicor88-and-zyie).

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you pass a base64 encoded string as data
Here is a blog post by AWS describing how to achieve that: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/binary-support-for-api-integrations-with-amazon-api-gateway/

Answer (score 1):

Can also use APIGateway s3 integration directly

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr Use the Lambda Proxy feature of API Gateway

API Gateway passes the raw request to the integrated Lambda function. 
 This request data includes the request headers, query string parameters, URL path variables, payload, and API configuration data.  In your example, you can pass in data and filename in a body request.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html