# How to submit form data to another website to retrieve data

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I am developing a website about educational results in which my visitors can check different educational institute results by entering their roll no. The problem is when my visitor clicks the submit button he/she redirects to the institute's webpage where he/she can find his/her result. I want to show results on my website. When visitor clicks the submit button my form submits to external website grabs data from their database and display back to my webpage.

I tried the following code:
You can check this page to better understand my problem:
http://www.results.doyouknow.com.pk/5th-class-results-online/

```html
<form id="result_form" class="form account-form" action="http://results.pec.edu.pk/" method="POST" target="_blank">
    <h1 style="font-size: 28px;">5th Class Result 2019</h1>
    <p style="clear: both; font-weight: bold; width: 100%; line-height: 40px;">Enter Grade 5 Roll No</p>

    <div style="width: 100%;">
        <div style="width: 23%; float: left;"><input id="roll_no" class="form-control" tabindex="" maxlength="2" name="roll_no1" type="number" placeholder="00" /></div>
        <div style="width: 23%; float: left;"><input id="roll_no" class="form-control" tabindex="" maxlength="3" name="roll_no2" type="number" placeholder="000" /></div>
        <div style="width: 23%; float: left;"><input id="roll_no" class="form-control" tabindex="" maxlength="3" name="roll_no3" type="number" placeholder="000" /></div>
        <div style="width: 23%; float: left;"><button class="button-5th" name="search">Search</button></div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to submit form values to results website grab data from their database and display it back to my website.

Comment: the only code here as per the tags used is "html".

Answer (score 0):

HTML form POST will take you to the `action` provided. 
Therefore for your case,

- You will have to do an API call to the server using http POST.
- Process the POST data on the end server and echo as JSON format.
- Get the values from the server via JSON and display it in your
  website.

You can do all this using basic Javascript.

Your source code will depend on the server-end language.

For PHP Backend, you can check here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24468752/10511088

Answer (score -1):

You can use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) or [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to get content of required website. You can show result on your web page as it is or you can use [simple html dom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to fetch the required data.

You can also use RSS and APIs if provided by website to access your required data.