# How to capture json data on php that is sent with ajax (no jquery)

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I am sending a json data to the server using ajax and pure javascript. How do I get the `$_POST` index that will display the json content on the php page?

ajax send a request as `key=value` to the server, meanwhile, by using the content-type 'application/json', I got an example on the link below as the json data (stringfy) was sent directly with no `key=value`.

[Sending a JSON to server and retrieving a JSON in return, without JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468459/sending-a-json-to-server-and-retrieving-a-json-in-return-without-jquery)

On the php side for post request, the example below was given.

```
$v = json_decode(stripslashes(file_get_contents("php://input")))
```

Now i don't understand what `php://input` signifies here since the json data was sent to the same page. I tried `file_get_contents('https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);` but it returned nothing.
I tried using `var_dump($_POST)` to view all the content as an array, but all i get is `array(0){}`.
So how do i actually catch the ajax (json) request i sent to a php page?
Here is an example of the code:

```
var data = {
    name : "john",
    Friend : "Jonny",
    Bestie : "johnson",
    neighbour: "john doe"
};
json = JSON.stringify(data);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest(), url = '../handler.php';
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log(this.responseText);
        };
    };
    ajax.open('POST', url, true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
    ajax.send(json);
```

PHP

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
var_dump($_POST); 
file_get_contents('https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

I expected the json string to be present in the $_POST variable and accessible by it's index after decoding the json string, but i get `array(0){}`, `null` or nothing displayed at all

Comment: try without stringify, and also check under network tab, your request, what is send in content

Comment: Based on the way you are sending the data, I believe that the data is part of the body and not the `POST`, so try grabbing the body of the request instead.

Comment: @AhmedSunny, I've tried that, without stringfy, the data being sent to the server is [object object] and still the same result.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, I don't understand clearly what you mean by the _the data is part of the body and not the POST_ . How do I grab the body of the request?

Comment: You should be able to get it like this:  `$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = json_decode($inputJSON);`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, thanks bro. I tried that and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an array, add the `true` argument to `json_decode()`. 
In your code:

```
$body = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
var_export($body);
```

To add the JSON data in $_POST, you can use this code.

In JS:

```
json = JSON.stringify(data);
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest(), url = '../handler.php';
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  };
};
ajax.open('POST', url, true);
ajax.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
ajax.send('jsn='+json);
```

In PHP:

```
$arr = isset($_POST['jsn']) ? json_decode($_POST['jsn'], true) :[];
var_export($arr);
```

Source: https://coursesweb.net/ajax/json-from-javascript-php

Comment: I think i just found a new protocol `php://input` and I'll  take time to know more about it. It worked. Thank you very much coursesWeb.

Comment: @UchennaAjah [Here is a list](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)