# How I can send json in request body with ajax ? just javascript and dont use jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, frontend

How can I send json in body request with ajax? Only use Javascript and do not use jQuery !!!
Someone can help
I remind you not to use jQuery!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can create function that work like jquery ajax request.

```
function AJAX(url, success, async) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
    } else {
        // IE6 and IE5 (unnecessary)
        var request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp");
    }
    if (async) request.onReadyStateChange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            success(request.status, request.responseText);
        }
    };
    request.open("GET", url, async);
    request.send();
    if (!async) success(request.status, request.responseText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't got the point. If all you need is to request an URL and send JSON body, you can achieve it simply with `XMLHttpRequest` :

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "url";
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log('RESPONSE');
    }
};
var data = {"email": "hey@mail.com", "password": "101010"}; // JSON YOU SEND
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Original answer here : [Sending a JSON to server and retrieving a JSON in return, without JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468459/sending-a-json-to-server-and-retrieving-a-json-in-return-without-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open('POST', '/your_url');
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    // success
    console.log(xhr.responseText); 
  } else {
    // other
    console.log('Error, status code = ' + xhr.status + ', response = '+xhr.responseText);
  }
};
var payload = JSON.stringify({param1: 1, param2: 'hello'});
xhr.send(payload);
```