# Connect to an API with URL Login and Password in Typescript / Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to Web programming, and I wanted to know how to make easy requests to connect to an API if the only information I have are the URL, a login and password using pure Typescript or Javascript.
The goal is to retrieve an access Token.

Comment: Please provide some more description like what you have tried till now and where exactly you stuck in implementation or understanding.

Comment: There is same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468459/sending-a-json-to-server-and-retrieving-a-json-in-return-without-jquery

Comment: @DevError404 I don't know the process to retrieve an access Token once the connection with the API is done, didn't found any question similar on stack.

Comment: are you using a browser or node?

Comment: @Ashwyn Horton I'm using a Browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise using the browsers fetch API which uses promises.

1. let us begin here. In the past browsers offered AJAX calls but ever since modern JS came through with promises, everything got really easy. You can find out more about `promises` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).
2. let us consider an example similar to your case where you have a `url` endpoint, and some data you want to send to the `url`. we expect that the `url` with respond with a `JSON` payload containing a `token`.

```
// so we will define our constants here
const url = 'http://localhost/login';

const username = 'username';
const password = 'password';

// now we configure the fetch request to the url endpoint.
// we should probably put it inside a separate function since
// you're using a browser, you probably will bind this request
// to a click event or something.
function login() {
  return fetch(url, {
    // in the case of a login request most APIs use the POST method offered by
    // RESTful APIs
    method: 'post', // can be 'get', 'put', 'delete', and many more

    // now we set any needed headers specified by the API
    headers: {
      // most APIs I have worked with use
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      // but some might need more, they will specify anyway.
    },

    // because we are using the 'post' method then we will need to add
    // a body to the request with all our data, body excepts a string so
    // we do the following
    body: JSON.stringify({
      username: username,
      password: password,
    }),
  })
  // Now we handle the response because the function returns a promise
  .then((response) => {
    // An important thing to note is that an error response will not throw
    // an error so if the result is not okay we should throw the error
    if(!response.ok) {
      throw response;
    }

    // since we expect a json response we will return a json call
    return response.json();
  })
}
```

3. now since you are using a browser you will have to bind the function to
   an element to trigger the call

```
// will define a self calling arrow function that will do the event binding

((button) => {

  button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    // we then call the function here.
    login()
    .then((response) => { 
      // side note, you could destructure the response argument as { token }
      // then just reference token instead.

      // recall that we expect this function to have a 'token' key in
      // the response payload...so let us log it just to make sure

      console.log(result.token);
    })
  });
// we add the button reference as the argument
})(document.querySelector('#submit'));
```

References:

[Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

[RESTful](https://restfulapi.net/)

I hope this helps give a better idea on the task you have, good luck

Answer (score 0):

u can use axios for js/ts
like this example :

```
getToken = () => {
    axios.post('http://localhost/login',{
      username: username,
      password: password,
    }).then((response) => {
        let data = response.data;
      //do whatever u want here eg :set token to local storage 
        localStorage.set('token',data.token);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
};
```

getToken();

Comment: I have an error with axios on browser: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: try to import it with cdn

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>